# Can't get Compass to work with RVM and Symfony on OS X Apache

Tags: macos, apache, symfony, rvm, compass-sass

I have the following project structure which I can't get to work:

- Mac OS X Lion with Apache
- PHP 5.3.6 and Symfony 2.0.6 running on this
- RVM with Ruby 1.9.2 and the compass 0.11.5 gem installed

On the command line I am able to run compass; but Symfony and `sudo -u _www compass` only get the following error message:

```
/Users/jan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find compass (>= 0) amongst [minitest-1.6.0, rake-0.8.7, rdoc-2.5.8] (Gem::LoadError)
from /Users/jan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /Users/jan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
from /Users/jan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/compass:18:in `<main>'
```

When I switch to the user _www (`sudo -su _www`) and run `rvm current`, I get `system`.
By switching to `rvm use 1.9.2`, I can run compass from the command line (as _www), but as soon as I close the Terminal, _www forgets that it should use Ruby 1.9.2 – `rvm use --default 1.9.2` does not work, either.

How can I set Ruby 1.9.2 for _www permanently (or get compass to work with _www another way)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try switching to `rvm system` and install the compass gem; this way you don't have to force _www to use Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: This works, but has anyone an idea how to get this running with the RVM version of Ruby 1.9.2?